# Sealed PhD Thesis

Tags: thesis

I came across a situation I haven't encountered before this week. I requested access to a PhD thesis from a group this week and was informed that it was not available as it was sealed for 5 years. The group explained that every student had the right to request that their thesis be sealed for 5 years.  The group is located in Austria.

Is requesting that your thesis be sealed ***from all access*** really an option? Is this specific to Austria?

Comment: You've already established that it is an option and that it's not just Austria. So what **is** your question now?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Then it would be good for that to be an answer.  My question stands.  The fact that the other question asks ***why*** you would do so implies an answer to this question but does not answer this question.

Comment: Is it possible the thesis reports proprietary information that public dissemination would decrease the value of? Like a new medical device that the student wishes to develop exclusively?